# How to set a "read-only checkbox" in PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to display the value of a Boolean variable using a `QCheckBox` widget, and render the user unable to change the displayed value. I don't want to disable it, as the resulting graying doesn't look good. I have tried to approximate the effect by changing the new value back to its previous value when the user clicks the `QCheckBox`. However, the problem is compounded by the fact that the state of the widget is described by the "checked" properties of the `QAbstractButton` parent class, and the "state" properties of the `QCheckBox` class itself. This gives rise to a combinatorial exercise of signals and slots, of which I have been unable to obtain any good result.

```
var_ctrl = QtGui.QCheckBox( 'some name' )

def rdslot1(state): 
    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        var_ctrl.setCheckState( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked )
    else:                               
        var_ctrl.setCheckState( QtCore.Qt.Checked )

def rdslot2(state): 
    if var_ctrl.isChecked():
        var_ctrl.setChecked(False)
    else:
        var_ctrl.setChecked(True)

# Signal/Slot combinations (only one should be active)
var_ctrl.stateChanged.connect( rdslot1 )
var_ctrl.toggled.connect( rdslot2 )
var_ctrl.stateChanged.connect( rdslot2 )
var_ctrl.toggled.connect( rdslot1 )
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party - it seems like you got a solution that works.  For future reference tho, another way you can do it would be to consume the mouse events - which keeps all of your signals working the way they should:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyCheckBox(QtGui.QCheckBox):
    def __init__( self, *args ):
        super(MyCheckBox, self).__init__(*args) # will fail if passing **kwargs
        self._readOnly = False

    def isReadOnly( self ):
        return self._readOnly

    def mousePressEvent( self, event ):
        if ( self.isReadOnly() ):
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyCheckBox, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent( self, event ):
        if ( self.isReadOnly() ):
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyCheckBox, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent( self, event ):
        if ( self.isReadOnly() ):
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyCheckBox, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    # Handle event in which the widget has focus and the spacebar is pressed.
    def keyPressEvent( self, event ):
        if ( self.isReadOnly() ):
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(MyCheckBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def setReadOnly( self, state ):
        self._readOnly = state

    readOnly = QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, isReadOnly, setReadOnly)
```

Setting the code up this way gets you a few things (which you may or may not care about) but can be useful when developing custom Qt widgets:

1. Consuming the event blocks the signal emission, so you can still connect other slots to things like clicked & toggled.  If you're looking for those signals and then just switching the value on/off - then other widgets listening for those signals will be triggered incorrectly
2. Using isReadOnly/setReadOnly keeps the class following the Qt coding style
3. Creating pyqtSignals & pyqtSlots will help if you expose the plugin to Qt's Designer

Answer (score 1):

Well later on I came up with a shortcut, which simply catches the clicks of the user and handles them according to a specifiable 'Modifiable' property. I have made this class:

```
class MyQCheckBox(QtGui.QCheckBox):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QCheckBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)        
        self.is_modifiable = True
        self.clicked.connect( self.value_change_slot )

    def value_change_slot(self): 
        if self.isChecked():
            self.setChecked(self.is_modifiable)
        else:
            self.setChecked(not self.is_modifiable)            

    def setModifiable(self, flag):
        self.is_modifiable = flag            

    def isModifiable(self):
        return self.is_modifiable
```

It behaves just like a normal `QCheckBox`, being modifiable by default. However, when you call `setModifiable(False)`, everytime you click it, it keeps the current state of the widget. The trick was to catch the `clicked` signal, not `toggled` neither `stateChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the checkbox widget, but override its look using widget [palette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html) or [style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: Hmm... sounds advanced. Not sure I get you correctly. Would you care to put or point to some example code?

Comment: I don't have an example code for you. I don't code Qt for some time. But here an interesting thread: http://www.qtforum.org/article/10564/which-color-setting-for-disabled-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

Make Another QLable on top of QCheckBox based on condition, it will stop checbox under it to be checked on unchecked.